# I'm trying to test Apple Push Notification service remote notifications but I'm getting an error

Tags: json, apple-push-notifications

I've found a tutorial about "houston" program to test remote notification on my app so I went on installed houston on terminal using `sudo gem install houston` then I type the following on the terminal to send push notification

```
apn push <6faed0c163edcd2615c0d94ftghc0bda4a879a040befd1793894d97f68ef4904> -P <{"aps":{"content-available":"1"}}> -c </Users/lukas-r8/Desktop/lucasAlves.pem>
```

I've got the device token that I get on delegate method of my app, then I set the JSON to send as notification (I just mean to wake up the app with this notification), and then my .pem certificate

the error I got is

> syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

if I remove the angle brackets I got...

> Exception parsing JSON payload: 784: unexpected token at
>   '{aps:{content-available:1}}'

how to fix these errors? is there any other easy way to test remote push notifications? I've set up everything apple require on my developer account, and in the app but I'm not able to send the request to APNs...

thank you in advance for the anwers

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes on 1 and try again, it should not be a string:

{
   "aps" : {
      "content-available" : 1
   }
}